# Angular js to execute commands in Putty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ssh, putty

Currently we are using Putty to connect to app server to view logs. I am in need of some way to automate this approach by using angular js. Is there any way that i can pass commands from my angular js/ or any client side based app to putty to execute commands and show it on browser or redirect that to the file.
Basically in the UI, i need to get the user credentials server details to view the app logs and rest should be automated.
So i need some means to pass data or commands to putty and execute them from client side.

Comment: at server, you can to use java, php or nginx plugins to execute commands and returns as a rest service

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, why not securely expose the logs via a Angular accessible protocol, like rest. Connecting to a SSH client via JS sounds unnecessary and overly complicated. If you really want to execute a local binary via Javascript, you could use the IE and ActiveX though.

Comment: ya i have done it using rest. But for rest service to run i need a server and then angular js to consume it an dshow it on screen. What i am looking for is some client side solution like without any backend. So that can run on any machine

Answer (score 0):

putty can be run from a cli. Here is a document to do so; http://etherealmind.com/putty-command-line/

Now you will need to brush up on the node.js documentation for child process spawning and handling; https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Some helpful modules for node.js would be hasbin, exec etc. should shorten dev time

Cheers